# Graphql Cannot create property 'clientMutationId' error on mutation?

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

this is the mutation I want to perform:

```
const GraphQLAddPlayerResponseMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
      name: 'AddPlayerResponse',
      inputFields: {
        cdx: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) },
      },
      mutateAndGetPayload: ({cdx}) => {
        var cdxAdded = addplayerResponse(cdx);
        console.log("cdxAdded = ",cdxAdded)
        return cdxAdded;
      }, // what u return on mutateAndGetPayload is available on outputFields
      outputFields: {
        playerResponse: {
          type: GraphQLInt,
          resolve: ({cdxAdded}) => {
            console.log("outputFields cdxAdded = ",cdxAdded)
            return cdxAdded
          },
        },
        viewer: {
          type: GraphQLUser,
          resolve: () => getViewer(),
        },
      },
    });
```

Can't figure out what's wrong with the code, it logs on the mutateAndPayload:

```
 mutateAndGetPayload: ({cdx}) => {
            var cdxAdded = addplayerResponse(cdx);
            console.log("cdxAdded = ",cdxAdded)
            return cdxAdded;
          },
```

but I think the outputFields is not evaluated since it's not logging in the console and I get this error:

```
{
  "data": {
    "addPlayerResponse": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot create property 'clientMutationId' on number '3'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "addPlayerResponse"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `return cdxAdded;` by `return { cdxAdded };` (wild guess)